# Связь моделей жизненного цикла и методологий разработки?

Tags: agile, scrum

Пожалуйста, объясните зеленому в этом вопросе. Существует множество моделей жизненного цикла и методологий разработки, как они взаимосвязаны? Т.е. с начала выбирается модель ЖЦ, потом методология? Или методологии уже созданы на основе какого-либо жизненного цикла? А также планы проектов строятся с учетом выбранной методологии, правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, но может кто-то подправит:

- Модель разработки программного обеспечения описывает, какие стадии
  жизненного цикла оно проходит и что происходит на каждой из них.
- Методология включает в себя набор методов по управлению разработкой: 
  это правила, техники и принципы, которые делают её более эффективной.
- Фреймворк – это более сформированная методология со строгими
  правилами, где все роли и процессы точно прописаны.
- Методология    покрывает определенные стадии жизненного цикла
  проекта.